# How to pass in the state to the dispatch action if using useState instead of this.state in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, use-state, redux-reducers

I am a beginner starting out in react and having difficulties in state management while working with **react-redux** and **useState**.
In the below code I am basically following a tutorial which passes in the `this.state` to the dispatch action `createProject` in the `handleSubmit` function as seen below.

```
class CreateProject extends Component {
  state = {
    title: '',
    content: ''
  }
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    })
  }
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // console.log(this.state);
    this.props.createProject(this.state);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <form className="white" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <h5 className="grey-text text-darken-3">Create a New Project</h5>
          <div className="input-field">
            <input type="text" id='title' onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <label htmlFor="title">Project Title</label>
          </div>
          <div className="input-field">
            <textarea id="content" className="materialize-textarea" onChange={this.handleChange}></textarea>
            <label htmlFor="content">Project Content</label>
          </div>
          <div className="input-field">
            <button className="btn pink lighten-1">Create</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    createProject: (project) => dispatch(createProject(project))
  }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(CreateProject)
```

Now, instead of using Class component I am using the functional component and using the `useState` hook. in the handleSubmit function how can I pass the state to the `this.props.createProject()` as `this.props` is not defined in-case of functional component and how to pass the state in place of `this.state`, will it be the `projectinfo` which stores the state or something else, I'm confused.

**TLDR;** I want to rewrite the `this.props.createProject(this.state)` line from the perspective of `useState` hook.

Below is the code I have written:

```
const CreateProject = () => {

    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    const [content, setContent] = useState('');


    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const projectinfo = { title, content }

        this.props.createProject(projectinfo);

    }
    return(
        <div className="container">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="white">
                <h5 className="grey-text text-darken-3">Create Task</h5>
                <div className="input-field">
                    <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" value={title} id="title" onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)} />
                </div>
                <div className="input-field">
                    <label htmlFor="content">Content</label>
                    <textarea id="content" className="materialize-textarea" onChange={(e) => setContent(e.target.value)}></textarea>
                   
                </div>
                <button className="btn pink lighten-1 z-depth-0">Create</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );

}

const mapDispatchToProps  = (dispatch) =>{
    return{
        createProject: (project) => dispatch(createProject(project)),
    };
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(CreateProject);
```

Any help or clues to understand this would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Also, props is undefined in the second code which is causing an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just want to add some way to do it using react hooks (specifically `useDispatch`).

With hooks, you don't need to use connect() and mapDispatchToProps. Instead, you can do it like this:

```
const CreateProject = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [content, setContent] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      const projectinfo = { title, content }

      // Use dispatch here
      dispatch(createProject(projectinfo));
  }

  return(
    <div className="container">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="white">
            <h5 className="grey-text text-darken-3">Create Task</h5>
            <div className="input-field">
                <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" value={title} id="title" onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)} />
            </div>
            <div className="input-field">
                <label htmlFor="content">Content</label>
                <textarea id="content" className="materialize-textarea" onChange={(e) => setContent(e.target.value)}></textarea>
               
            </div>
            <button className="btn pink lighten-1 z-depth-0">Create</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CreateProject
```

`createProject()` is your action creators.

You can read more about `useDispatch` here:
https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch

Answer (score 1):

Your dispatch isn't working because you're trying to access it via `this.props`. Assuming that `createProject` call inside the dispatch call in mapDispatchToProps is valid and there is a `createProject` function available in the scope of that file, what you need to do is this:

```
const CreateProject = (props) => { // Get props from the parameter.

    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    const [content, setContent] = useState('');


    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const projectinfo = { title, content }

       props.createProject(projectinfo); // Replace this.props and use props

    }
    return(
        <div className="container">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="white">
                <h5 className="grey-text text-darken-3">Create Task</h5>
                <div className="input-field">
                    <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" value={title} id="title" onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)} />
                </div>
                <div className="input-field">
                    <label htmlFor="content">Content</label>
                    <textarea id="content" className="materialize-textarea" onChange={(e) => setContent(e.target.value)}></textarea>
                   
                </div>
                <button className="btn pink lighten-1 z-depth-0">Create</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );

}

const mapDispatchToProps  = (dispatch) =>{
    return{
        createProject: (project) => dispatch(createProject(project)),
    };
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(CreateProject);
```

This would work. I hope this answered and solved your issue.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but if I remove props.createProject(projectinnfo) then how would I pass the state to the dispatch action?

Comment: Hi. You don't have to remove it, just replace the line with what I gave in the answer. I'm guessing you looked at it before I had updated. I had fixed my wording after I wrote my original answer, but probably it didn't update for you at the time.

Comment: I see you took the `useDispatch` route. I didn't suggest it because I assumed you were not using it based on your comfort level. A lot of people I know have been taking their time completely moving to hooks while my colleagues and I jumped right in when hooks had been introduced.

Comment: Yeah, I am also pretty much new to hooks and it eases working with state, so `useDispatch` worked for me and pretty easy to understand.